# Deepcopy of two lists

Tags: python, deep-copy

I have two lists in python, which stores some class instances in different manners (e.g. order). Now, I would like to create a copy of these two lists for some purpose (independent from the existing ones). To illustrate my problem clearly, I created a demo code below.

```
import copy

class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.node_id = 0

node = Node()
list1 = [node]
list2 = [node]

u_list1 = copy.deepcopy(list1)
u_list2 = copy.deepcopy(list2)

id1 = id(list1[0])
id2 = id(list2[0])
u_id1 = id(u_list1[0])
u_id2 = id(u_list2[0])
```

By using deepcopy operation, I created two new lists `u_list1` and `u_list2` that are independent from `list1` and `list2`, which is what I need. However, I find an issue. The node instance in `u_list1` and `u_list2` are also independent now. They have different addresses in memory. Is it possible that the same instances in `u_list1` and `u_list2` still share one address just like instances in `list1` and `list2`?

What I need is `id1 = id2`, `u_id1 = u_id2`, while `id1 != u_id1`.

Comment: Just a maybe more Pythonic way to write the requirement: `id2 == id1 != u_id1 == u_id2` :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `deepcopy`'s memo aspect by deep copying them together:

```
u_list1, u_list2 = copy.deepcopy((list1, list2))
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) (emphasis mine):

> Two problems often exist with deep copy operations that don’t exist with shallow copy operations:
>
> - Recursive objects (compound objects that, directly or indirectly, contain a reference to themselves) may cause a recursive loop.
> - Because deep copy copies everything it may copy too much, such as data which is **intended to be shared** between copies.
>
> The deepcopy() function avoids these problems by:
>
> - **keeping a memo dictionary of objects already copied** during the current copying pass; and

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't run into that approach before.

Comment: Pretty nice answer!